# JQuery Animation Recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I am trying to ensure that my animations happen one after each other but I cannot get the functions to only be executed once. The method that I send in is being called twice and this gets doubled when I call the recursive one.

```
window.onload = function() {
    blink(function() {
        console.log("Done");// <-- 4 times :(       
    });
};

function closeEyes(delay, onComplete) {
    var pos = parseInt($('.eye').css('margin-top')) + 16;  
    $('.eye').animate({'margin-top' : pos + "px"}, { duration: delay, queue: false, complete: onComplete});
    $('.eye').animate({'height' : '4px'}, { duration: delay, queue: false});                                 
}

function openEyes(delay, onComplete) {    
    var pos = parseInt($('.eye').css('margin-top')) - 16; 
    $('.eye').animate({'margin-top' : pos+'px'}, { duration: delay, queue: false, complete: onComplete});
    $('.eye').animate({'height' : '32px'}, { duration: delay, queue: false});        
}

function blink(onComplete) {
    //called ONCE
    closeEyes(250, function() {
        //called TWICE
        openEyes(250, onComplete); //<-- onComplete is executed 4 times
    });    
}
```

Comment: The four-times problem could be solved with `$.when()`, but actually you don't need to set a callback because the animations are automatically chained.

Comment: Thank you! when() works perfectly! I was worried about the 2 functions bing executed back to back

Comment: Do you mean an infinite loop opening and closing eyes?

Comment: Well I need to close the eyes, then open the eyes. I will be repeating this several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the answer - I asked the guys at work. After creating a fiddle we realised that I had 2 classes that use "eye" - and so the complete closure was being called for each one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16474054)

Comment: @shabeer Actually it does - if you create a JSFiddle (Which SO does not like having links of and thus why it's not included here) with ONE eye it works as expected, but add extra HTML elements with the same class and it starts compounding. This makes all kinds of sense when you start thinking about the implementation. That coupled with the fact that I am the author and therefore would know when my question is answered.

Comment: In a community forum it would useful to post a snippet on how solved your problem. So other with same issue will know how to solve it rather than saying you found an asnwer .

Comment: I apologise for thinking SO developers would understand that the code is actually fine and that the problem was having multiple div's with the same class. I assumed a simple solution to a problem was the best, but clearly I was wrong. However I am also not prepared to make it longer for the sake of a review.

Answer (score 0):

A recursion is suppose to call itself,
then, adding a counter is needed to invalidate it.

```js
function blink(times, onComplete) {

  return $
    .when(closeEyes(250))
    .then(function() {
      return times 
        ? blink(--times, onComplete)
        : (complete || $.noop)()
      ;
    })
  ;
}
```